# How to use PROGRAM clause of Postgres COPY command with Powershell command

Tags: java, postgresql, powershell

I have postgres version 9.5
i want to execute PROGRAM clause of Postgres COPY command with Powershell command to import csv data into table

i try to execute following command in postgres 9.5
**COPY [table name] FROM PROGRAM 'powershell -command { Get-Content "file path " | Select -skip 1}' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;**

Error:-
**DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 255**

please help us 
thank you

Comment: Does the command `powershell -command { Get-Content "file path " | Select -skip 1}` work as expected from a cmd.exe shell prompt? Is `"file path "` fully qualified and/or is the current directory correct?

Comment: yes it is working fine on windows powershell. The  file path is qualified { Get-Content "D:\mbean.txt" | Select -skip 1 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just i need to remove "{"  "}"  and it is working correctly**
Query is follow below 
**COPY [table name] FROM PROGRAM 'powershell -command  Get-Content "file path " | Select -skip 1' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ;**